# How can I know amount of cores in the CPU for elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I want to limit pool size by amount of CPUs. How can I know amount of cores in the CPU for elixir?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [System.schedulers_online/0](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#schedulers_online/0) to get the number of available schedulers. This defaults to the number of cores.

This can be configured on boot with the `+S` flag http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+S

If you really need the number of cores then you can use:

```
:erlang.system_info(:logical_processors_available)
```

You can see this option (and many others) on http://www1.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info-1

Comment: `System.schedulers_online/0` returns 8 on my hyper threaded quad core. However, on macOS `:erlang.system_info(:logical_processors_available)` returned `:unknown`.

Comment: On a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), the call `:erlang.system_info(:logical_processors_available)` also returned `:unknown`, but two other arguments returned the correct number (12): `:logical_processors` and `:logical_processors_online`

Comment: The documentation of Erlang about `:erlang.system_info/1` doesn't clarify the reason why one works for Mac and another too, but I think it is interesting to know the difference between them: with `:logical_processors` it returns the detected "number of logical processors configured in the system", while `:logical_processors_available` returns the available on the Erlang runtime system and `:logical_processors_online` returns the ones online, although I am not clear on the meaning in this case (could it be in use?).